# Strange behaviour on Enter pressed

Tags: asp.net, html

I am developing an ASP.net Web Application. I have an weird incident right now:

I got a Master Page which contains the Menu and some other stuff. It also contains in the right Upper corner 2 Buttons two switch language.

The weird thing is, when a user in the content Page presses Enter in a disabled textbox the German Button gets pressed. This behavior isn't implemented in any form.

Here is the code for the Button:

```
  <asp:ImageButton ID="german" runat="server" AlternateText="de-AT" ImageUrl="~/Design/img/german.gif"
                meta:resourcekey="germanResource1" OnClick="english_Click" style="" />
                <br />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="english" runat="server" AlternateText="en-US" ImageUrl="~/Design/img/english.jpg"
                meta:resourcekey="englishResource1" OnClick="english_Click" style="" />
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong, or how to fix this?

Comment: It is likely to be that the browser is taking the pressing of enter to be a form submission action and so is doing the post back with the first button on your form being the one considered pressed. I've a recollection that its just IE that sends a button press (others might submit but I don't know if they consider a button to be pressed). I don't have solutions to hand (hence just a comment) but it might give you another place to look if no answers are forthcoming quickly.

Comment: The OnClick for the German ImageButton is pointing to the english_Click event, is this correct?

Comment: Yes its just not properly named ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suppose you can use

```
Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnGo.UniqueID;
Page.Form.DefaultFocus = txtGo.UniqueID;
```

in the Page_Load to set a default button and focus,
also you could put the buttons at the bottom of the html and use css to position them to the top part of the page

Answer (score 0):

If you have a panel that wraps the content on the content page, you could set the default button property on the panel to a submit button, which should stop this happening.